# How can I make a variable constant (not change its value) in NLog.config file when some other target variable is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, nlog

Have created a NLog.config file in which have some variables defined and some target parameters, When I make some change in the target variable the file gets re-read and the variable value is also reset to initial value in the file even if I have changed it through code.
I dont want the variable to reset its value if it is being changed from code or if any other variable value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this:

```
<variable name="defaultLogDir" value="c:/defaultdir/"/>
<targets>
   <target name="logfile" type="file" fileName="${gdc:overrideDir:whenEmpty=${defaultLogDir}}/hello.txt" />
</targets>
<rules>
   <logger name="*" writeTo="logfile" />
</rules>
```

Then just configure the overrideDir using GDC in code:

```
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("overrideDir","c:/mydir/");
```

GDC has the limitation that you cannot include layout-renderers like `${shortdate}`.

But yes it would be nice if `keepVariablesOnReload=true` was a little smarter, so it only applied to variables that had been modified after config was loaded (Right now one has to restart to modify nlog-variables in config file). You are welcome to create a [feature request](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new/choose).

Comment: This is in fact the following feature request IMO. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1429